# where do I define this rails method for an associated model in a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

How do I define the user method in my mailer?

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in AppointmentsController#create
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

From this line:

```
mail to: service.user.email, subject: "Appointment Confirmation"
```

I have users with many services and each service can have an appointment.

When someone makes an appointment, I want the user who owns the service for which that appoint was made to get an email.

My appointments controller looks like this:

```
before_action :load_services, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]

def create
  @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @appointment.save
      ClientMailer.client_confirmation(@appointment, @service, @user).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @appointment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def load_services
  @services = Service.all.collect {|service| [ service.title, service.id] }
end
```

`client_mailer.rb` looks like this:

```
class ClientMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "bookme@example.com"

  def client_confirmation(appointment, service, user)
    @appointment = appointment
    @service = service
    @user = user
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: service.user.email, subject: "Appointment Confirmation"
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: "error undefined method for user" This is not a Ruby error message. Please post the exact text of the error message and which line in your code it refers to.

Comment: okay - i just added in the error messages. thanks.

Comment: you have `@services` in `load_services ` method but you have mentioned: `@service` in `client_confirmation(@appointment, @service, @user)` ? are you sure that's correct?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you don't pass any *service* to *def client_confirmation*.

You're trying to pass **@service** but it's not defined anywhere. You have **@services** defined in before action. Then you need to set **@service** filtering **@services** with some conditions you know about.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have on-to-one association between `Appointment` and `Service` classes, you can change the following code of your controller.

From:

```
ClientMailer.client_confirmation(@appointment, @service, @user).deliver
```

To:

```
ClientMailer.client_confirmation(@appointment, @appointment.service, @user).deliver
```

Please note that this scenario also assumes that you have one-to-many association between `User` and `Service` classes.

Comment: Oh - no... its set up like: a User has many Services and a Service has many appointments. A User has many appointments through services.

Comment: then I guess you should extract the Service from `appointment_params ` being sent to server when someone creates and appointment(and maybe selecting a service)?

Comment: yeah. a service is always selected in order to create an appointment. i'll try it.